Chrome periodically reloads every tab at once
I'm running the latest version of Chrome, updating fairly regularly. My PC remains on with Chrome open 24/7.
Every now and then (perhaps once a month, approximately) every single tab will refresh at the same time. If I'm listening to a catchup radio show or podcast, it may jump back to the beginning, etc.
At least once it has done it in the night and though my PC is locked, I come downstairs in the morning to it loudly playing music. If I was away and this happened it could be very annoying to my housemates (who don't know my password or have access to my office).
It must have happened at least 4 times and I cannot find what is going on or why. Is this a bug or some setting I might change?

It happens at random times, and not necessarily when I'm using it - it's not when I create a new tab for example, Chrome will be open in the background and spontaneously every tab gets a spinny wheel and reloads.

Does it coincide with automatic updates?

@ChanganAuto I'm pretty sure not as I don't think it's set to auto-update (can't find a setting for this though)

The suggestions below were reported as helpful (although reported for
refreshes more frequent than once a month):

Turn Off Chrome’s Memory Saver : In Settings > Performance.
Use an extension :

Tab Auto Refresh,
set to "No Auto-Reload".
Disable automatic tab discarding.




@Mr.Boy: Did you look at this?

That setting is already turned off.

Do the extensions help?
